# HTML slim Email Templates for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, templates, slim-lang

Just recently started to work on an ongoing project and I need to integrate templates for the email layout. 
I have admin_mailer.rb in app/mailers/admin_mailer.rb which contains below:

```
class AdminMailer < ApplicationMailer

  before_action { @all_admins = AdminUser.all.pluck(:email) }
  default to: -> { @all_admins }

  def contact(contact_message)
    @message = contact_message.question
    @name = contact_message.name
    @email = contact_message.email
    mail subject: I18n.t('emails.contact_request', name: @name), from: @email
 end
end
```

and in app/views/admin_mailer/contact.html.slim I have

```
- content_for(:header) do
  title= t('emails.contact_request')


h2 #{@name} some text here
p sender: #{@name}
p email: #{@email}
br
p message: #{@message}
```

I googled html.slim email templates and encountered this one: https://gist.github.com/mkhairi/7eee8bea87a63171563e but not able to make the template appear

How can template be used for contact.html.slim file so that layout would change. Do you happen to know other templates that can be used for ruby on rails?

Comment: Have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

there is slim to html converter online.convert it to html and save it in erb file.